# Is there a way to declare two nexus url in maven for searching single artifact

Tags: java, maven, nexus, xl-deploy

I'm trying to fetch an artifact from the nexus URL and I want maven to search for it in first Nexus URL and if it fails to find, it should look for it in the second URL.

To be precise I want to add multiple repositories for XL Deploy.
Here's the format.

```
                  <deployables>
                        <was.War name="petclinic-war">
                            <contextRoot>petclinic</contextRoot>
                            <fileUri>maven:com.xebialabs.deployit.demo.petclinic:PetClinic:war:1.0</fileUri>
                             <tags>
                                <value>server1</value>
                             </tags>
                        </was.War>
                    </deployables>
```

[Here's the link of the XL Deploy config page](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xldeploy-maven-plugin/5.0.x/examples/external-artifact-reference.html)

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple repositories as guided [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html) like:

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>repo_1</id>
     <name>repo_1_name</name>
     <url>repo_1_url</url>
   </repository>
   <repository>
     <id>repo_2</id>
     <name>repo_2_name</name>
     <url>repo_2_url</url>
   </repository>
 </repositories>
```

Comment: How can we extend it for  <fileUri>maven:com.xebialabs.deployit.demo.petclinic:PetClinic:war:1.0</fileUri> formate. I have added the refrence in my question

Answer (score 0):

This is easily configured in newer versions of XLD: https://docs.xebialabs.com/v.9.5/xl-deploy/how-to/configure-xl-deploy-to-fetch-artifacts-from-a-maven-repository

Alternatively, if you have a repository manager (e.g. nexus, artifactory) you can always proxy multiple repositories there and configure that in XLD.